# Independent Nexys 4 clocks desynchronizing over time

Tags: verilog, hardware, hdl

We are developing a program which needs synchronized clocks on two devices to measure the fly time of ultrasound signals.

The problem is that when we synthesize the program and test it on two independent Nexys4 FPGAs the distance tends to decrease over time (0.13 cm/s). This ratio is constant, and always decreasing, leading us to think that the problem is in the code.

And when we synthesize the program in only one Nexys 4, no decrease is seen over time.

We have a module to listen for signals (3 signals per slave, and 3 slaves) called dataListener: the signal SendCommand is the control signal for an UART module which sends the direction and command to an SRF02 ultrasound, this module is exactly the same on both devices.

```
module dataListener(
    input mclk,
    input clkSync,
    input reset,
    input rxDataRdy,
    output wire[7:0] command,
    output reg[7:0] direction,
    output reg read,
    output reg sendCommand,
     output reg dataChanged,
     output reg [1:0] slave,
     output reg [1:0] sensor
    );

parameter dir0 = 8'd0;
parameter dir1 = 8'd3;
parameter dir2 = 8'd6;

parameter rangingCommand = 8'd87;
parameter readCommand = 8'd94;

//parameter clkTime = 0.000000001; // 1ns Simulation // 10ns FPGA
//parameter windowTime = 0.08; // 80 ms
//parameter listenTime = 0.07; // 70ms
parameter windowCyclesDuration = 8000000;
parameter listenCyclesDuration = 7000000;

reg [54:0] windowCounter;
reg emitSent;
reg readSent;

reg slave1;
reg slave2;
reg slave3;

assign command = emitSent ?  readCommand : rangingCommand;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

always @(posedge mclk) begin

    if( reset )begin
        sensor <= 2'b0;
        windowCounter <= 55'b0;
        emitSent <= 0;
        readSent <= 0;
          slave <=0;
    end else begin
          if( clkSync ) begin

            if( windowCounter >= windowCyclesDuration )begin //Window ended
                windowCounter <= 55'b0; //resetCounter
                emitSent <= 0;
                readSent <= 0;
                if( sensor == 2'd2 )begin
                        sensor <= 2'b0;
                        if(slave == 2'd2)
                            slave <= 2'b0;
                        else
                            slave <= slave+1'b1;
                end else begin
                    sensor <= sensor + 1'b1;
                end       
            end else begin
                windowCounter <= windowCounter + 1'b1;  //Window in process
                if(!emitSent)begin
                    sendCommand <= 1;         
                end
                else if( (windowCounter >= listenCyclesDuration) && !readSent)begin //listen done, time to send the read command
                    sendCommand <= 1;         
                end           
            end

            if(sendCommand)begin
                sendCommand <= 0; //Shut down "sendCommand" signal.
                if(!emitSent)
                    emitSent <= 1;
                else
                    readSent <= 1;
            end
        end
        /// Process incoming data 
        if( rxDataRdy )begin
            read <= 1;  
        end else if( read )begin
            read <= 0;

        end 
    end
end

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
always @( sensor ) begin
    case(sensor)
        2'd0: begin
            direction <= dir0;
        end
        2'd1: begin
            direction <= dir1;
        end
        2'd2: begin
            direction <= dir2;
        end
        default: begin
            direction <= dir0;
        end
    endcase
end

endmodule
```

A module on the slave device which sends the commands:

```
module slave(
     input mclk,
    input clkSync,
     input reset,
     output [7:0] command,
    output [7:0] direction,
     output reg sendCommand,
     output inWindow
    );

parameter numSlave = 2'b0;          //Between 0-2
parameter dir=8'd0;                 //Depends on the slaves direction
parameter comm=8'd92;

assign command = comm;
assign direction = dir;

parameter windowCyclesDuration = 8000000;

reg [54:0] windowCounter;
reg [1:0] sensor, slave;
reg commandSent;
assign inWindow = (slave == numSlave);

always @(posedge mclk) begin

    if( reset )begin
        windowCounter <= 55'b0;
          sendCommand <=0;
          commandSent <= 1; 
          slave <= 2'b0;
          sensor <= 2'b0;
   end else begin
          if( clkSync ) begin
            if( windowCounter >= windowCyclesDuration )begin //Window ended
                windowCounter <= 55'b0; //resetCounter
                     commandSent <= 0; 
                if( sensor == 2'd2 )begin
                        sensor <= 2'b0;
                        if(slave == 2'd2)
                            slave <= 2'b0;
                        else
                            slave <= slave + 1'b1;
                end else begin
                     sensor <= sensor + 1'b1;
                end       
            end else begin
                    windowCounter <= windowCounter + 1'b1;  //Window in process
                    if( inWindow && !commandSent)begin //im in my window and command not sent yet
                        sendCommand <= 1;//send when a new window is about to begin
                        commandSent <= 1;
                    end
            end 

                if(sendCommand)begin
                    sendCommand <= 0; //Shut down "sendCommand" signal.
                end
          end       
    end
end

endmodule
```

The signal `clkSync` is only activated when both devices are 'Sync', which happend only at the start of functioning through a cable which is then remove to allow movement.

Here is the sync module of the master:

```
module SyncM(
    input mclk,
    input reset,
    input response1,
    input response2,
    input response3,
    output reg call1,
     output reg call2,
     output reg call3,
    output reg clkSync,
     output reg slave1,
     output reg slave2,
     output reg slave3
     );



always @ (posedge mclk)   begin

    if(reset)begin
        clkSync <= 0;
        slave1 <= 0;
        slave2 <= 0;
        slave3 <= 0;
        call1 <= 0; 
        call2 <= 0;
        call3 <= 0;
    end else begin

        if( btn && !call1 )begin    
            call1 <= 1;
            call2 <= 1;
            call3 <= 1;
            clkSync <= 1;
        end

        if(response1)
                slave1 <= 1;

        if(response2)
                slave2 <= 1;

        if(response3)
                slave3 <= 1;
    end
end
endmodule
```

And the slave sync module, the `call` signal is send from the master to slave by a cable.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module SyncS(
    input reset,
     input call,
    output reg clkSync,
    output reg response
    );


always @ (reset or call) begin

    if(reset) begin
        clkSync <= 0;
        response <= 0;        
    end else begin
        if (call) begin
            response <= 1;
            clkSync <= 1;
        end
  end
end
endmodule
```

Comment: On one board, are you using 2 independent crystal oscillators when it stays in sync? I suspect not, so you are seeing the oscillators drift in frequency. Use the same oscillator for both, connected from one board to the other, or communicate a sync signal via an RF link if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't understand all of your code. But, the problems seems to be, that you rely on the external oscillator on your FPGA board. If you use two boards, both oscillators will not run on exactly the same frequency. So, if you compensate for the phase shift right only once after startup, the clocks will desynchronize after some time. That's why it worked with just one board.

There are two possible solutions:

- Use just one clock source (oscillator) and forward the clock to other board.
- Periodically compensate for phase shifts.

Both solutions require a more or less steady connection between both boards.